# How to list all timers of another form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer, components

I want to make a procedure that stops all timers of any given form. Though when building it says

> "components' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Form".

Here is the code:

```
Public Sub _Timers_Stop(frm As Form)
        For Each itm As Object In frm.components.components
           If TypeOf (itm) Is Timer Then
               itm.stop()
           End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That's because `Form` doesn't have a `components` property (just like the error says).  You can only call properties that exist.  Instead of `frm.components.components`, try `frm.Controls`.

Comment: @StevenDoggart : Unfortunately components are not part of the `Controls` collection.

Comment: @LamineAbed : The `components` property/field is only created by the Visual Studio designer and you're required to cast `frm` into one of your specific forms in order to be able to use it (unless it is marked as `Private` or `Protected`).

Comment: Just make a list or array of timers a public property of that form, that'd be the easiest way to directly access them. The frm.Controls collection of your form probably contains a lot more than just a few timers

Comment: thanks guys :) ill try

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection for this:

```
Public Sub StopTimers(Form As Form)
    For Each Item In Form.GetType.GetFields(Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public).Where(Function(x) TypeOf x.GetValue(Form) Is Timer)
        Dim Timer As Timer
        Timer = Item.GetValue(Form)
        Timer.Stop()
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As I was corrected in the comments, the `Controls` collection does not contain components--it only contains controls.  The references to the non-visual components, such as timers, are held in a private `Container` field, typically called `components`.  That `Container` field is not a part of the base `Form` class at all.  It is declared and implemented separately, on each form that needs it, by the form designer.  Since it's not a member of the base class, there is no easy way to access it on any given form.  Even if it was a member of the base class, accessibility would still be an issue since it's typically declared as a private field.

The safe way to do this, which retains proper type-checking, would be to create an interface:

```
Public Interface IFormWithComponents
    ReadOnly Property Components As ComponentCollection
End Interface
```

Which you could then implement on every form, as applicable:

```
Public Class MyForm
    Implements IFormWithComponents

    Public ReadOnly Property Components As ComponentCollection Implements IFormWithComponents.Components
        Get
            Return components.Components
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

And then your timer-stopping method could take that interface as its parameter:

```
Public Sub _Timers_Stop(frm As IFormWithComponents)
    For Each t As Timer In frm.Components.Cast(Of Component).OfType(Of Timer)
       t.stop()
    Next
End Sub
```

However, if you don't really care about the type-checking, and you don't mind the slight decrease in performance, you can alternatively use reflection to find the private field in the form object and extract its value:

```
Public Sub _Timers_Stop(frm As Form)
    Dim timers As IEnumerable(Of Timer) = frm.
        GetType().
        GetFields(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Public).
        Select(Function(fieldInfo) fieldInfo.GetValue(frm)).
        OfType(Of Container)().
        SelectMany(Function(container) container.Components.OfType(Of Timer)())
    For Each t As Timer In timers
        t.Stop()
    Next
End Sub
```